# How to find C# files without a namespace in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, namespaces

It's come to light that at least one file within a subdir in my project had no namespace set, causing issues.

How can I find any other files missing a namespace?

I searched Google and Stack Overflow to no avail. I'd imagine it could be done with a RegEx Find in Files, but my RegEx is a little rusty.

Comment: just grep for files that don't contain the actual word `"namespace"`? Visual Studio doesn't give you errors with the relevant files?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I'm on a Windows system, without `grep`. VS indeed doesn't throw any errors. I reckon it was probably only the one class affected, but I'd like to double-check.

Comment: Control+Shift+F regex search for "negative lookahead 'namespace' then anything"

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum This is what I asked in the question... how do I do a negative search in Find in Files?

Comment: @DannyBeckett honestly I'd just write C# code that does `File.ReadAllText` and using `.Contains` on the result after using `Directory.GetFiles` to get all the file names. So   `Directory.EnumerateFiles("baseProjectPath", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Select(f => new {text = File.GetAllText(f), name = f}).Where(f =>! f.text.Contains("namespace")).Select(f => f.name0` and then print that.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum That's overkill imo; there is a RegEx option in the bog-standard Find dialog. I appreciate your help though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi I have observed one straightforward thing that built in Visual studio itself. Open the solution in Visual studio and

> Click on View > Object Browser

. Here It lists all the dlls and Projects. If you expand each project first it shows namespaces and inside them it shows sub items as Classes, Interfaces, Enums, Delegates ... . If any class doesn't have a namespace then it will be in Classes folder outside the namespace

> Other way is

If your code is compiling fine, then you can check the compiled EXE or DLLs in the 'IL disassembler'.

To open the GUI, go to `Start > Programs > Visual Studio 2013 > Visual Studio Tools > VS2013 x64 Native Tools Command Prompt` and execute `ildasm`.

Classes without a namespace will be listed separately, and classes with a namespace will be listed in their respective groupings.

Comment: Hi I have observed one straightforward thing that built in Visual studio itself. Open the solution in Visual studio and Click on View > Object Browser. Here It lists all the dlls and Projects. If you expand each project first it shows namespaces and inside them it shows sub items as Classes, Interfaces, Enums, Delegates ... . If any class doesn't have a namespace then it will be in Classes folder   outside the namespace.

Comment: if you like this I will update my answer and you can mark this question as answered. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you can get ReSharper, it adds an option in the right-click menu for projects (and possibly the solution) to [adjust namespaces](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Refactorings__Adjust_Namespaces.html) - that should pick up any classes that aren't in the correct namespace, based on the directories that each file is in.